# Nomad Template : Folder is created instead of file

Tags: ubuntu, nomad, percona-xtradb-cluster

Why is it that when checking the container **test.cnf** is a directory instead of a file based on the templete stanza, can you check it please

```
  config {
    image = "percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7"
    volumes = ["/tmp/new.conf:/etc/mysql/test.conf"]

    port_map {
      db = 3306
      gc = 4567
      ss = 4444
      ist = 4568
    }
  }

  template {
    data = <<EOH
      binlog_format=ROW
      default_storage_engine=InnoDB
      !include /etc/mysql/node.cnf
    EOH
    destination   = "/tmp/new.conf"
  }
```

Comment: According to the documentation, it appears Nomad only supports directory bind volume mounting for the Docker driver: https://nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker/#inlinecode-volumes-4

Answer (score 1):

There solution is to use `mounts` instead of `volumes`.
https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker/#mounts

This is an excerpt from Docker documentation. Nomad has to follow that specification to work with Docker.

> The type of mount, can be either volume, bind, tmpfs, or npipe.
>   Defaults to volume if no type is specified.
>   `volume`: mounts a managed volume into the container.
>   `bind`: bind-mounts a directory or file from the host into the container.
>   `tmpfs`: mount a tmpfs in the container.
>   `npipe`: mounts named pipe from the host into the container (Windows containers only).

Since `bind` mount type allows you to bind files from host to container I suggest you [use the bind example from the documentation](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker/#mounts).